# Azure continuous webjob (blob) triggering only once

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have an Azure webjob that has a few blob triggered functions within. I uploaded this to Azure via the Add job dialog on the portal and set it to "Run Continuously" The behavior  expected was that any time a blob is added /modified to the containers specified in the blob trigger the corresponding function be called. This however does not happen.

The only way to trigger the functions (after having uploaded blobs) is to **Stop the web job** and **restart** it again.

Every time I restart the job the **functions
seem to be triggered and triggered only once**. Any **subsequent blob updates don’t seem to trigger them again.**

On the portal however the WebJob shows as 'Running' however no functions get triggered after the initial trigger.

The main function for this web job looks like this :

```
static void Main()
{
    var host = new JobHost();                
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

What could be the issue ?
The trigger functions are standard blob triggered functions and work for the first time - hence I am not yet sharing that code.

UPDATE
The function signature looks like this

```
public static void UpdateData([BlobTrigger("inputcontainer/{env}-update-{name}")] Stream input, string name, string env, TextWriter logger)

public static void DeleteData([BlobTrigger("inputcontainer/{env}-delete-{name}")] Stream input, string name, string env, TextWriter logger)
```

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.  I am getting the same results as you.  https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/507

Comment: I know this question is over a of year old, but I just noticed it. Were you ever able to figure out the issue? There have been quite a lot of improvements to how we listen to blobs since then. I added a link in the github issue to our latest builds if you are able to give them a try.

Answer (score -1):

Because of how the blob triggers are implemented, it can take up to 10 minutes for the function to be invoked.

If the function is not triggered even after 10 minutes, please share with us the function signature and the names of blobs that you are uploading.

Comment: I have seen my blobs not been consumed for over a day - after which i manually restart the job and the blob triggers. Have updated my original post with function signatures.